# How to edit a converted lead?

Tags: lead-conversion

Due to a bug in one of our own flows, some leads were converted, but their status did not have the corresponding value (the flow changed the Converted status back to some other status).

So IsConverted was true, but the status had a contradictory value. Trying to change this, e.g. by using the Workbench, resulted in this error: `CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD` (even though I am a sysadmin).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a special app permission for this: `View and Edit Converted Leads permission`.

Create a permission set with this app permission, assign it to the appropriate persons and now you can do anything you want with converted leads.

This is the [Salesforce help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.leads_view_edit_converted.htm&type=5).